# Sum strings that represent time

Tags: c#, time

In my `WPF` applicatin I have some strings that look like `0:22:49`, `0:08:00`, `0:06:31`,.. the format is `hour:minute:second`, and I need to sum those strings as time for further calculations, like division and square root

---

To be more certain, I need to calculate the `average` and `standard deviation` of this set of times

Comment: Can you please clarify, if the data is `hour:minute:second`, what do mean by performing division and square root on it?

Comment: I need to calculate the average and standard deviation of those times @VikasGupta

Comment: Ok.. in that case, I don't think Timespan directly supports division and square root.. You'd have to choose a suitable unit, like seconds, or minutes (`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`), perform those operations on those values, and then convert them back to `TimeSpan` if needed (`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the `TimeSpan` class and convert to Ticks, Milliseconds, Seconds or Minutes, depending on the precision you need in your calculations. After you do the calculations, you can convert back to Timespans.

> To be more certain, I need to calculate the average and standard deviation of this set of times

Here is a sample of the calculations you need for Sum, Average and Standard deviation:

```
var values = new []
{
    TimeSpan.Parse("0:22:49").TotalSeconds,
    TimeSpan.Parse("0:08:00").TotalSeconds,
    TimeSpan.Parse("0:06:31").TotalSeconds
};

var sum = values.Sum();
var avg = values.Average();
var stdev = Math.Sqrt(values.Average(v => Math.Pow(v - avg, 2)));


var total = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sum);
var average = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(avg); ;
var standardev = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(stdev); ;

Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + total);
Console.WriteLine("Avg: " + average);
Console.WriteLine("StDev: " + standardev);
```

Answer (score 5):

*Well*, I think you just need to use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
var t1 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:22:49");
var t2 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:08:00");
var t3 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:06:31");
var total = t1 + t2 + t3;
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Result will be;

```
00:37:20
```

Just remember, `TimeSpan.Parse(string)` method uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default. That means if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`TimeSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not `:` (Most cultures have `:` but not all), this parsing operation will fail.

In such a case, you can use [`TimeSpan.Parse(String, IFormatProvider)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783872%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

> Thank you! Can I use division and square root on TimeSpan as well?

Sure you can, but not *directly*. You can use [`Total*` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `TimeSpan` structure which all returns numbers as a `double`. You can divide them to each other and can use [`Math.Sqrt` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.sqrt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) either.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use division and square root on TimeSpan as well?

Comment: @Yona Sure you can. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert them to [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) then add them up

```
vat total = TimeSpan.Parse("0:22:49") + TimeSpan.Parse("0:08:00") + TimeSpan.Parse("0:06:31")
```

total will equal 00:37:20